# Radio button inside listView is not triggering in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have declared a listView like this :

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource QuestionList; ItemClick ButtonClick"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_questions"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
```

Now my item template contains choice mode questions which is rendering as per the requirement but whenever i click on any radio button its not triggering any event. I have take all the selected values from the radio button.
Below is my code of item template:

```
<RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionA; Click ItemChecked" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionB; Click ItemChecked"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionC; Click ItemChecked"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionD; Click ItemChecked"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

I also implemented the wrapper class as suggested. Below is my wrapper class code:

```
public class ListViewWrapper
    {
        Question _question;
        QuestionsViewModel _parent;

        public ListViewWrapper()
        {

        }

       public ListViewWrapper(Question radio, QuestionsViewModel parent)
       {
           _question = radio;
           _parent = parent;
       }

       public IMvxCommand ItemChecked
       {
           get
           {
               return new MvxCommand(() => _parent.btnClick(_question));
           }
       }

       public Question Item
       {
           get
           {
               return _question;
           }
       }

   }
```

Here's ViewModel :

```
     private IMvxCommand _buttonClick;
            public IMvxCommand ButtonClick
            {
                get
                {
                    _buttonClick = _buttonClick ?? new MvxCommand<Question>(btnClick);
                    return _buttonClick;
                }

            }



public void btnClick(Question item)
    {
        //Do something 
    }
```

Comment: What does _QuestionList_ return? It should return the list of wrapped question items, since that is what the item template is bound to.

Comment: QuestionList contains set of questions and their respective options like "Hello World" and then their options Yes, No , May be. Also when I'm binding Click radio button becomes disabled  and when I try to bind it with onClick event then radio button remains enabled but on console it is shown that  binding is  failed.

Comment: I've changed the radio button to button but the problem is my button gets disabled when I bind the click event with it however when i remove the binding button gets enabled